# htmleditorextender cannot upload image

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am trying to implement the Ajax control toolkit htmleditorexteder in a web form but I am getting the following error:

```
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Sys.ArgumentException: Cannot deserialize empty string.
```

I do not know how or why this error is happening. my attempts to search on the internet have been unsuccessful. Any advice you could give would be greatly appreciated

Also the align buttons don't seem to work. when I switch it to code view it displays the align property but does not align the text to the right or in the centre not sure why.

My aspx:

```
<ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender EnableSanitization="true" ID="HtmlEditorExtender1" OnImageUploadComplete="HtmlEditorExtender1_ImageUploadComplete" DisplaySourceTab="true" TargetControlID="txtPost" runat="server">
                    <Toolbar>
                        <ajaxToolkit:Undo />
                        <ajaxToolkit:Redo />
                        <ajaxToolkit:Bold />
                        <ajaxToolkit:Italic />
                        <ajaxToolkit:Underline />
                        <ajaxToolkit:StrikeThrough />
                        <ajaxToolkit:Subscript />
                        <ajaxToolkit:Superscript />
                        <ajaxToolkit:InsertOrderedList />
                        <ajaxToolkit:InsertUnorderedList />
                        <ajaxToolkit:CreateLink />
                        <ajaxToolkit:UnLink />
                        <ajaxToolkit:RemoveFormat />
                        <ajaxToolkit:BackgroundColorSelector />
                        <ajaxToolkit:ForeColorSelector />
                        <ajaxToolkit:FontSizeSelector />
                        <ajaxToolkit:Indent />
                        <ajaxToolkit:Outdent />
                        <ajaxToolkit:InsertImage />       
                    </Toolbar>
                </ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPost" runat="server" BackColor="White" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="30"></asp:TextBox>
```

My code behind:

```
protected void HtmlEditorExtender1_ImageUploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
{       
    string fullPath = "~/images/postAssets/" + e.FileName;
         // Save upload file to the file system
       HtmlEditorExtender1.AjaxFileUpload.SaveAs(MapPath(fullPath));
       e.PostedUrl = Page.ResolveUrl(fullPath);
}
```

**Edit:**

I have tried adding:

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd"
      type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, 
      AjaxControlToolkit"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

As suggested by one of the answers but I got the following error:

```
HTTP Error 500.23 - Internal Server Error
An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.
Most likely causes:
•This application defines configuration in the system.web/httpHandlers section.
```

When debugging the onImageUploadComplete event does not get fired but I do not know why.

Still stuck on this guys so any help would be enormously appreciated I am at a total loss.

**Finally some good news :)**

I have finally got the imageupload to work! yay!
I added the following to my web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
<handlers>
  <add name="AjaxFileUploadHandler" verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd" type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, AjaxControlToolkit"/>
</handlers>
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295"/>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd" type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, AjaxControlToolkit"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

**However**

The text align buttons still only align to the left, produce html like the following:

```
<p align="right">This is some test</p>
```

but it does not actually align the text to the right? Is there anyway I could change this so instead it produces:

```
<p style="text-align:right">This is some text</p>
```

If I manually enter the html I can make it align by using the above line of html but the person who will be using the form has zero knowledge of html and css and has no interest in learning. Which is why I went with this control in the first place.
Also is there a way to have it automatically add the following to the textbox before any edits, in which all the users input will go?:

```
<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12">
<!-- html editor extender content goes here -->
</div></div>
```

My final request is not so important but the text align buttons is vital so I definitely need those working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the config setting for this. you can do as something like this...

```
<system.web>
....
<httpHandlers>
    <add verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd"
      type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, 
      AjaxControlToolkit"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

You can take idea from this link where the same problem is occurring with different control.

In this Post, it is explain it better way.

Hope this will help you.

thanks

Comment: hi @Mukesh Kumar, thanks for your answer. There is no link. Would you be able to edit so I can check out the link?

Comment: I have updated my answer. would you be able to review my edits and see if there is any other things you could suggest?